# Exact sequence of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $R$ be a ring. Let's say we have an exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$0\rightarrow P\rightarrow R^2 \overset{f}\rightarrow R\rightarrow 0,$$

where $P\cong\ker(f)$.

Because of $R$ being a free $R$-module, the sequence splits and hence we have an $R$-homomorphism $g:R\rightarrow R^2$ such that $f\circ g=1_R$. Further we know that $P\oplus R\cong R^2$ and this means that $P$ is a stably free module of type $1$.

In the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181072084)<sup>1</sup> (page 779) I am reading  it says that $P=\mathrm{Im}(1_{R^2}-g\circ f)$.

<sup>1</sup>Richard G. Swan. "Quaternionic Bundles on Algebraic Spheres." Rocky Mountain J. Math. 26 (2) 773 - 791, Spring 1996.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathrm{Im}(1 - gf) = \ker(f)$.

$f((1 - gf)(x)) = f(x) - fgf(x) = 0$, so $\mathrm{Im}(1 - gf) ⊆ \ker(f)$.

On the other hand, if $x ∈ \ker(f)$, then $(1 - gf)(x) = x$, so $\ker(f) ⊆ \mathrm{Im}(1 - gf)$.

Comment: Thanks! The first inclusion was already clear to me but I still did't get the second one. While reading this I also get the second one :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x \in R$,  then $f( x -g \circ f(x)) = f(x) - f\circ g \circ f(x)$. Note $f \circ g$ is the identity on $R$.